# Issue in installing twilio module

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install [twilio for nodejs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install). These lines are coming up in console.

```
npm WARN twilio@0.4.0 package.json: 'modules' object is deprecated
twilio@0.4.0 ./node_modules/twilio
```

How to get rid of this ?

I am using `npm install twilio` command.

I tried to download and copied in node_modules folder but that is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the package.json file which is a specially formatted file used for the npm package management system. Certain values are required and some of those key names have changed over the years and some just have been removed. The error you are getting is due to the package.json file still using the modules key:

```
},
"modules": {
    "client": "./lib/twilio",
    "twiml": "./lib/twiml"
},
```

https://github.com/sjwalter/node-twilio/blob/master/package.json#L13

Even though you are getting this error it should not effect your usage of the module. It was still installed and everything should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [open bug report](https://github.com/sjwalter/node-twilio/issues/17) for this, but it doesn't seem to have gotten much attention.